# How to add new columns in time-partitioned tables in Google big query

Tags: google-bigquery

I try to add new columns in a BigQuery time-partionned table. I use the bq command line tool (not API) because I use Talend for BigData for loading.

In a normal table, the following command succeed :

```
bq update -t dataset.Mytable newcol:type
```

On time-partitioned table, I have "Provided Schema does not match Table MyTable"

When I try to add my new field in the Google Console, it succeed too but I don't have the command to do this. Anyone knows if is it possible and how ?

I have to add the column instead of recreating the table because I don't want to lose my partitions / history.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the command would succeed on a normal table. You have to provide the full schema instead of just the new column.

```
bq mk MyDataset.MyTable f1:string
Table 'MyProject:MyDataset.MyTable' successfully created.
bq update -t MyDataset.MyTable f2:string
BigQuery error in update operation: Provided Schema does not match Table
bq update -t MyDataset.MyTable f1:string,f2:string
Table 'MyProject:MyDataset.MyTable' successfully updated.
```

Comment: You're right. I test the command on an empty normal table. I will try with the entire schema. Thank you for idea !